# Como entender e lidar com o custo do Azure?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, microsoft-azure, asp.net-core, gerenciamento-de-projetos, microsserviços

Já conheço o Azure faz bastante tempo, li bastante e vi vários videos mas nunca usei ele. O que eu sei sobre o pagamento é que você só paga por aquilo que usa.

Acontece que recentemente um conhecido conversou comigo sobre um projeto que está querendo desenvolver, porém ele queria hospedar em um servidor dedicado que a empresa dele possui. Quando eu ouvi o projeto eu vi que na verdade o Azure seria mais adequado pelos recursos, aí ele disse que viu a calculadora e que percebeu que "facilmente se chega a um custo de 10 mil por mês".

Isso me preocupa um pouco, porque se for assim, só empresas maiores teriam condições de usar a plataforma, e ela seria inviável para empresas menores e desenvolvedores que estão iniciando um projeto.

Ao mesmo tempo, acho inviável atualmente desenvolver um projeto hospedando em um único servidor dedicado, devido ao alto acoplamento que isso vai gerar entre as diversas partes do aplicativo.

O que me pareceu, entretanto, foi que esse preço alto que ele percebeu foi por não ter muita noção do que incluir na calculadora de preço. De fato, mesmo entendendo como programar usando os recursos do Azure, eu não sei estimar com aquela calculadora.

O que eu quero saber é: realmente chega-se facilmente a custos tão altos no Azure? Ele de fato é inviável para um aplicativo que está começando e, portanto, não terá muita receita durante um bom tempo?

Levando em conta que claramente o Azure satisfaz melhor as necessidades do aplicativo, como eu poderia lidar com o problema do custo se ele for de fato alto? Uma alternativa que pensei foi construir tudo usando Docker, hospedar no servidor dedicado mesmo, e quando não suportar mais, migrar pro Azure. Essa seria uma alternativa viável, ou teria outra dentro do Azure mesmo?

Answer (score 4):

A questão principal é que recursos você quer consumir do Azure? 
Pois para cada serviço oferecido existem vários "Níveis de serviço". A alguns recursos tem **níveis até gratuitos**. 
Por exemplo, para o serviço de Aplicativo Web, existem os níveis:

- Gratuita e Compartilhada
- Plano de serviço Básico
- Plano de serviço Standard
- Plano de serviço Premium
- Plano de serviço Premium v2
- Plano de serviço isolado

O que irá variar para cada plano é o número de núcleos, memória ram, armazenamento, load balance, backups & restore, disponibilidade dedicada do servidor.

Por isso preço varia muito do primeiro ao último nível. O objetivo disso é atender todo o tipo de empresa e não apenas a grandes empresas.

Answer (score 4):

#### Realmente chega-se facilmente a custos tão altos no Azure?

Sim, você consegue chegar a custos altos se não configurar adequadamente os recursos que realmente precisam. A proposta do Cloud Elástico é exatamente escalar à medida que for necessário, ou seja, você pode utilizar o Azure pagando absolutamente 0 ou tendo o custo altíssimo, isso tudo vai da configuração.

#### Ele de fato é inviável para um aplicativo que está começando e, portanto, não terá muita receita durante um bom tempo?

Não é inviável, pelo contrário, acho que é totalmente viável uma vez que você pode começar utilizando recursos que não tem custo, como as camadas Gratuitas e Compartilhadas, existem serviços no Azure que até na camada gratuita o limite é mais do que suficiente para um projeto piloto, ou que esteja iniciando.

Para você ter ideia, o serviço de Push Notification do Azure possui uma camada gratuita de 1.000.000 de mensagens. O Serviço de Aplicativo (HOSPEDAGEM DE SITE) possui uma camada FREE com 1GB de Ram e 1GB de Disco. 1 Banco de Dados SQL Server na camada mais em conta, fica em torno de R$ 20,00.  Isso são só alguns exemplos que citei, ou seja, se tudo for utilizado de forma correta, creio que o seu custo não será alto. Acredito que quando o seu produto exigir um custo alto do Azure pode ter certeza que você estará faturando com o mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

> O que eu quero saber é: realmente chega-se facilmente a custos tão altos no Azure?

Sim, bem facilmente, pois é muito fácil escalar qualquer serviço nele - exitem instancia de Azure SQL que custam USD 22K/mes.

> Ele de fato é inviável para um aplicativo que está começando e, portanto, não terá muita receita durante um bom tempo?

Não, claro que não, se vc consome pouco, irá pagar pouco. Porém, é importante lembrar que o Azure, principalmente se usar PaaS, vc praticamente substitui funcionários. Existem empresas que possuem apenas desenvolvedores, e nenhum cara de IT Pro, pois usam apenas PaaS. E se transferir o custo de um funcionário IT Pro para uma infra em nuvem, a nuvem é bem mais vantajosa.

> Levando em conta que claramente o Azure satisfaz melhor as necessidades do aplicativo, como eu poderia lidar com o problema do custo se ele for de fato alto? Uma alternativa que pensei foi construir tudo usando Docker, hospedar no servidor dedicado mesmo, e quando não suportar mais, migrar pro Azure. Essa seria uma alternativa viável, ou teria outra dentro do Azure mesmo?

Em um primeiro contato, é normal leigos criarem hospedagem imaginando como se fosse servidor. Quando se provisiona um PaaS, vc escolhe o poder de processamente que será dedicado à aplicação e não a todo servidor. Exemplo: Se eu for hospedar um SQL Server em um Windows Server, vou precisar de uns 16GB RAM - essa memória será compartilhada entre o sistema operacionar, o SQL Server, e para hospedar o swap de dados que minha aplicação irá consumir. Já com PaaS, eu só seleciono essa ultima, a **memória dedicada à minha aplicação**. Então posso, por exemplo, usar apenas 4GB RAM, pois minha app está iniciando, e não precisa mais que isso em swap.

O mesmo ocorre para hospedagem WebApp, muitos colocar 8Gb, 16Gb e 8 cores. Mas fazem pensando que esse recurso será compartilhado com a VM, e não é caso, se é WebApp, é PaaS, então vc escolhe o que será dedicado à sua aplicação. Tenho apps rodando no mínimo - Standard A1, o mínimo recomendado para produção - que tem só 1 core e 1.75Gb RAM, mas isso é o dedicado para minha app.